# Find largest number of not sorted array without using linear and binary

Tags: c++, c

As far as i know, the only possible way to find largest number and lowest number if they array is not sorted by using linear search.

is there any other option for this one? just want to know tho

Comment: It's linear, but you can parallelize it with threads and SIMD.

Comment: And `max(floor(3/2(N−1)), 0)` comparisons (instead of `2*(N-1)`) to find both (min AND max) at once (see `std::minmax_element`).

Comment: If you are given the array right away - it's always linear. But, for instance, if you are getting the element on by one, you can save the max/min elements on the fly. Well, still linear, but hidden within the linearity of the input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the value of a particular element in an unsorted collection tells you nothing about the value of adjacent elements, you need to inspect every value.

And doing that is O(N).

Answer (score 2):

Nope, there is none. Complexity of finding largest/smallest element of an unsorted sequence is always `O(N)` comparisons.

Answer (score 2):

There is no other way. You have to inspect each and every element. The complexity of algorithm always will be `O(n)`